# OnTriggerEnter2D being triggered by colliders not marked as trigger?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a standard Top-Down 2D RPG. On my Player object, I have two colliders, one is a regular box collider 2D not marked as trigger handling the collisions and it is smaller than the player vertically. I have another box collider 2D which is marked as trigger, working as a hitbox of sort, and it covers the whole player-. While picking up items, I wanted to use the trigger collider so I used this code :

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.GetComponent<DroppedItem>() != null && other.isTrigger)
    {
        Debug.Log("Picked up item.");
        DroppedItem item = other.GetComponent<DroppedItem>();
        inventory.AddItem(item.item, item.itemAmount);
        Destroy(item.gameObject);
    }
}
```

The debug message is triggered twice each time I collide with the dropped item, which also has a trigger collider, even though I destroy the item afterwards. The debug message is also triggered twice if I mark the trigger collider as non trigger, or vice versa. How do I avoid this?

Comment: is this component with this code is on multiple objects? and yes in general it is enough if one of he object is a trigger (see [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html))

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* that you need to have the collider on the player, and the trigger on the item. Then, a script needs to be attached to the item which calls a function on the player which adds items, and then in the script you can destroy the item. The only reason I can think of for why this is being called twice is that your script is on both the item and the player.

[image: Simple Diagram]

(Simple diagram with some pseudocode)